# Select item from a string of items

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a string of email recipients in the format like this:

```
 DECLARE @recipients VARCHAR(MAX);
 ....
 PRINT @recipients;
 /* the result
 person1@yahoo.com;person2@hotmail.com;person1@yahoo.com;...
 */
```

"SELECT DISTIECT ..." is a simple and powerful SQL statement, but it works against a table. Is there a simple way to select **distinct** recipient from the recipient list variable like FOR loop in C# or Ruby?

```
 FOR @recipient IN @recipients
 BEGIN
    -- send email to @recipient
 END
```

By the way, I am using TSQL in SQL server 2005.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution for you that uses a temporary table.

```
declare @emails varchar(2000)
set @emails = 'person1@yahoo.com;person2@hotmail.com;person1@yahoo.com;'

declare @results table (row int identity(1,1), email varchar(500))

while ((select charindex(';',@emails)) > 0)
begin   
    insert into @results select substring(@emails,1,charindex(';',@emails))
    select @emails = substring(@emails,charindex(';',@emails)+1,len(@emails))
end

select distinct email from @results
```

The idea is to continously parse the email from the string, insert it into a temporary table, and remove the parsed email from the remaining string.

You can use loop through the temporary table afterward to send your individual emails.

Answer (score 1):

e.g.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split (@sep char(1), @s varchar(512))
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN (
    WITH Pieces(pn, start, stop) AS (
      SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s)
      UNION ALL
      SELECT pn + 1, stop + 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s, stop + 1)
      FROM Pieces
      WHERE stop > 0
    )
    SELECT pn,
      SUBSTRING(@s, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 512 END) AS s
    FROM Pieces
  )
GO
```

Comment: I got error:
Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "start" of recursive query "Pieces"

Comment: OK. I got the error resolved. I used @s varchar(max). Not sure why max is not working here. 512 or 4000 is OK

Answer (score 0):

What you want in a Split function that will return a table for you to work with.

There are uncountable implementations [around](http://www.google.com/search?q=sql+server+split) but I'm not aware of a built-in one, or a consensus of the 'best'.

Comment: Your suggestion looks like this is not a simple TSQL way. The function takes two parameters, one of recipients and another as delimiter like ';' as default. Is that right?

Comment: Sure.  You can make the delimiter whatever you like as default. As far as "simple T-SQL way" - functions are a built-in part of T-SQL, Table Valued functions have been around since SQL Server 2005 I believe.

Comment: @David Chu: there is no 'simple' way in Sql Server.

Comment: Until SQL supports arrays, you will have to achieve this the manual way - by parsing a delimited string.

Answer (score 0):

I use a function like the one below to deal with a similar situation when receiving lists like that from the front end. Then you can just use this code to return the string as a table instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT String FROM dbo.GetTableFromStringList(@recipients)
```

You probably want to do the actual sending of the email in something other than T-SQL code though.

Here's the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetTableFromStringList]
(
    @StringList VARCHAR(1000),
    @Delimiter  CHAR(1) = ','
)
RETURNS @Results TABLE
(
    String  VARCHAR(1000)   NOT NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        @string     VARCHAR(1000),
        @position   SMALLINT

    SET @StringList = LTRIM(RTRIM(@StringList)) + @Delimiter
    SET @position = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @StringList)

    WHILE (@position > 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @string = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@StringList, @position - 1)))

        IF (@string <> '')
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @Results (String) VALUES (@string)
        END

        SET @StringList = RIGHT(@StringList, LEN(@StringList) - @position)
        SET @position = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @StringList, 1)
    END

    RETURN
END
```